# How to crop the image in objective c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

The user can change the cropbox size which is shows default in edit screen. I tried with below code :

```
- (UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef); 
    return cropped;
}
```

But it cropped fixed area. How to crop area which is selected by user ?

Comment: Try and pass different CGRect to your given function it will working. I don't think so any problem is in your code. Problem in your basics on language. I recommend, please read some books or apple docs on Objective-C.

Answer (score 29):

**For Get Crop Image:**

```
UIImage *croppedImg = nil;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake("AS YOu Need"); //set your rect size.
croppedImg = [self croppIngimageByImageName:self.imageView.image toRect:cropRect];
```

Use following code for call  **croppIngimageByImageName:toRect:** method that return `UIImage` (*with specific size of image*)

```
- (UIImage *)croppIngimageByImageName:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        //CGRect CropRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height+15);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
        UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        return cropped;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
    CGRect clippedRect  = CGRectMake(0 ,0,180 ,180);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imgVw1.image.CGImage, clippedRect);
    UIImage *newImage   = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    imgVw1Cliped.image=newImage;

    NSLog(@"%d",imgVw1Cliped.image.imageOrientation);
```

Comment: @user2677875 when u r satisfied with answer then please upvote this answer.. bcz ur upvote will help full for Mohit..
and this answer working in my project.

Comment: @Mohit this code doesn't seem to be working anymore. Gives an error for ios8.