# AVFoundation Image Capture - Capturing Exactly what the user sees in a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, avfoundation

I know this has been asked before, I've tried all of the answers to this question on here and I think that there is something fundamental about this which I don't understand so my efforts are fruitless so far. I'm hoping someone can make me feel like an idiot for struggling with this and point me in the right direction.

All I'm trying to do is capture a square UIImage with AVCaptureSession and display it in a thumbnail image view looking exactly the same as the area in the video layer. The image capture works fine, however, when the image is added to my thumbnail image view, the top and bottom of the image is expanded to show areas of the photo which aren't in the AvCaptureVideoPreviewLayer visible to the user.

The following code initialises my session, it all works but maybe there's something I need to change here to capture only the part of the feed visible to the user:

```
-(void)setupFeed
{
    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];
    if([self.session canAddInput:deviceInput])
    {
        [self.session addInput:deviceInput];
    }

    self.cameraPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session];
    [self.cameraPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    CGRect frame = self.cameraPreview.frame;
    [self.cameraPreviewLayer setFrame:frame];
    [rootLayer insertSublayer:self.cameraPreviewLayer atIndex:0];

    self.imageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [self.imageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [self.session addOutput:self.imageOutput];

    [self.session startRunning];
}
```

The next bit of code is to capture my image, this code also works, cropping aside:

```
[self.imageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
    {

        if(imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL)
        {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            self.snappedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [self.snappedImage crop:self.snappedImageView.layer.frame];
            [self.session stopRunning];;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
            [self presentSnappedImageOptions];
        });
    }];
}

-(void)presentSnappedImageOptions
{
    [self.imagePreview setImage: self.snappedImage];
}
```

...and finally the UIImage category method which I'm using to attempt to crop the image to the same as the visible video layer:

```
@implementation UIImage (Crop)

- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect
{

    rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x*self.scale,
                      rect.origin.y*self.scale,
                      rect.size.width*self.scale,
                      rect.size.height*self.scale);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef
                                          scale:self.scale
                                    orientation:self.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}

@end
```

Any help will be greatfully recieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your views are layed-out but maybe the cropping rect you're using, "self.snappedImageView.layer.frame" does not correspond to the area of the captured image displayed by the preview layer.

As I understand the the preview layer's frame is squared, right, and since it's video gravity is aspect filled, i think you could just get the biggest centered square for the image and use that as the cropping rect.

How about you try this rect

```
CGSize size = image.size;
CGFloat side = fminf(size.width,size.height); //just the smaller dimension
CGrect croppingRect = CGRectMake((size.width-side)/2.f,(size.height-side)/2.f,side,side);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with this. Your code gave me the GCRect I needed, I then had to use a different cropping method to get the desired results. For anyone struggling with the same thing, the cropping method I used was - (UIImage *)croppIngimageByImageName:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect, posted by iPatel here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205672/how-to-crop-the-image-in-objective-c .