# How to allow user to crop a fixed frame of an image iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image

I am trying to find a way to allow the user to select what part of an image he/she wants to use. But the crop size is fixed, so the user can't adjust how big or small they want the photo.

In my mind, the screen would display the photo with a rectangle over it, which the user could move around with his/her touch. Then press "OK" and the image would be cropped wherever the rectangle was.

Right now my code is:

```
(UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef); 
return cropped;
}
```

This code automatically crops the image from the center without giving the user the chance to crop it him/herself.

I'm thinking something along the lines of this:
[image: Instagram example]

In the above image, the user moves the picture around in the background until the part within the box is what they want to keep, while cropping the rest. They can also zoom in and out on the photo by pinching.

Comment: [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=crop) may help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to crop the image in objective c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205672/how-to-crop-the-image-in-objective-c)

Comment: i am using the same code for now because it at least gets the job done, but it is not at all what im hoping for