# Objective-C: draw and crop image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, crop

i am new to Objective-C. Now i want to get source code to crop image after user draw on image. it would help me lots in my project.

thank you everybody.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205672/how-to-crop-the-image-in-objective-c

Answer (score -1):

try these library from **GitHub**..

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor

i hope it helps..

Comment: dude, i want the library that user can draw then crop image with user drawing shape. :)